# Issue running Installshield compiled setup.exe unattended on Windows 8.1 under system account

Tags: windows, batch-file, psexec, sccm

Okay so I am deploying a program via SCCM 2012 to all of our laptops at our corporate office. I have the program for the package install with administrative rights so it is running under the SYSTEM account. This works perfectly on all of our Windows 7 PC's, however all of my Windows 8.1 laptops/tablets are returning error code -3 to SCCM. This means the required data was not found in the setup.iss file. I did some testing and ran the batch file that is kicking all of this off with PSEXEC -s on a windows 7 machine and it exited with code 0, so a successful install as I had expected. When I run this same test on a Windows 8.1 machine it exits with code -3 just as I was seeing in my SCCM console. I tried to recapture a new setup.iss by recording the install on that windows 8.1 machine and used that .iss in the PSEXEC test and got the same result. The kicker is that if I open an elevated command prompt and kick off the batch the program installs! So there seems to be something different with how the SYSTEM account is handling this batch file in Windows 7 vs Windows 8. Has anyone else seen something like this or have any idea why it would be failing when run as SYSTEM *only* on Windows 8.1?

Comment: Can you show the batch its running?

Comment: Oh yes I can clearly see it running, and get a log file of its output when i enable verbose logging. The log contains some lines toward the end about not having access to a particular directory in what seems like the middle of the install process and then it exits with code -3. Very strange issue. Since it is just a handful of devices we installed the program manually, using the exact same batch file just ran from a command prompt running under the local Administrator account instead of System. I have never had this issue previously so I have to assume it is the way this exe was compiled.